# Sequence of elements, but "join is unavailable: call the 'joinWithSeparator()'" error

Tags: swift-playground

Why do I get the error "join is unavailable: call the `joinWithSeparator()`" at line 16 (the last line below) when I try to run it on playground? And, how can I fix it?

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    let gender = "female"

    func fullName() -> String {
        var parts: [String] = []

        if let firstName = self.firstName {
            parts += [firstName]
        }

        if let lastName = self.lastName {
            parts += [lastName]
        }
        return " ".join(parts)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message *tells* you what the problem is, and it *tells* you how to fix it. *Read* the error message! *Do* what the error message says!

```
return parts.joinWithSeparator(" ")
```

Comment: Dear Matt, the first word of question is "why" and this error message doesn't tell us WHY `join` is unavailable... today. So, why is 'join' unavailable in this case?

Comment: @ValentinShergin Because the Swift standard library evolved. And it will keep evolving. In Swift 3, `joinWithSeparator` is gone too.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer to "why"-part of question is:

Because String's method `join` was removed in Swift 2. 
So, actually, it is not "unavailable", it just doesn't exist in Swift 2 at all.

SUDDENLY.