# Create a string separated with new lines (\n) from an Array using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

I am facing a problem during the development of my iOS application, what I am trying to achieve is to create a single string from an array of strings. The array contains the address of a given location, obtained from a reverse geocoding using `CLGeocoder`, this is the code that gives me the array of strings:

```
let userCoordinates = CLLocation(latitude: mapView.userLocation.location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.userLocation.location!.coordinate.longitude)

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userCoordinates, completionHandler: {
    placemark, error in

    let reverseGeocodedLocation = placemark?.first?.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [String]
}
```

`reverseGeocodedLocation` in my case is:

```
["Apple Inc.", "Cupertino, CA  95014", "United States"]
```

The result string should separate the strings in the array and present them in a multi-line format like this:

```
Apple Inc.
Cupertino, CA 95014
United States
```

I have tried searching on the web for a solution and I found this code that should do that, and this could be the solution:

```
print("\n".join(reverseGeocodedLocation.map({$0})))
```

But the compiler says:

> Cannot invoke 'join' with an argument list of type '([String]?)'

Comment: It changed in Swift 2, you'll have to use `reverseGeocodedLocation!.joinWithSeparator("\n")`. (I used `!` here but its better to safely unwrap it first).

Comment: @HennyLee Thank you for your comment, this happens to be the correct answer to my problem, but since it's a comment I can't mark it as the answer to my question, please post it so I can do it

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688387/sequence-of-elements-but-join-is-unavailable-call-the-joinwithseparator. – Did you even *try* to find similar questions?

Comment: @MartinR I *did* tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if let reverseGeocodedLocation = reverseGeocodedLocation {
    print(reverseGeocodedLocation.joinWithSeparator("\n"))
}
```

As an answer instead of a comment.

Swift 3/4:

```
reverseGeocodedLocation.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: That was quick haha.