# how can I make that label go down a line between every string

Tags: arrays, swift, uilabel

I have this array of string
I want it inside the label so that every string has line

```
"method": [
    "Bring a large frying pan of salted water to the boil over medium-high heat. Add the asparagus and cook for 2-3 minutes or until bright green and tender crisp. Use tongs to transfer the asparagus to a plate. Cover to keep warm.",
    "Add the vinegar to the water in pan. Reduce heat to medium-low. Crack 1 egg into a small bowl. Use a spoon to stir the water to make a whirlpool. Carefully pour the egg into the centre of the whirlpool. Cook for 4 minutes for a soft yolk or until cooked to your liking. Use a slotted spoon to transfer to a plate. Cover with foil to keep warm. Repeat with remaining eggs.",
    "Divide the asparagus among serving plates. Top with an egg. Season with salt and pepper. Top with parmesan to serve."
]
```

I want it inside the label so that every string has line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a string separated with new lines (\n) from an Array using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720185/create-a-string-separated-with-new-lines-n-from-an-array-using-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
let arrayStr = [ "Bring a large frying pan of salted water to the boil over medium-high heat. Add the asparagus and cook for 2-3 minutes or until bright green and tender crisp. Use tongs to transfer the asparagus to a plate. Cover to keep warm.", "Add the vinegar to the water in pan. Reduce heat to medium-low. Crack 1 egg into a small bowl. Use a spoon to stir the water to make a whirlpool. Carefully pour the egg into the centre of the whirlpool. Cook for 4 minutes for a soft yolk or until cooked to your liking. Use a slotted spoon to transfer to a plate. Cover with foil to keep warm. Repeat with remaining eggs.", "Divide the asparagus among serving plates. Top with an egg. Season with salt and pepper. Top with parmesan to serve." ]
```

**SwiftUI**

```
Text(arrayStr.joined(separator: "\n\n"))
```

**Storyboard**

```
label.text = arrayStr.joined(separator: "\n\n")
```

Comment: ' func test()-> NSArray{
                    let myarray:NSArray = recipes?.method as! NSArray
                    return myarray
                }'.    I have this function already can integrate with this code?

Comment: Protocol 'NSArray.Element' (aka 'Any') as a type cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'       it gives me this error

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the examples added in the answer. The answer shows you how to separate each line in your array in a label.